# Does cachegrind gives performance data for kernel modules

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, x86, profiling, valgrind

I am facing a performance issue on my embedded box which is x86 based. I have installed valgrind on it, but so far it looks that it gives the performance data for application program but if I want to check the performance data for the kernel drivers, how can I do that?

Is there any tool which can help do that, by rebuilding the kernel with some options or anything..

Really appreciate any help!!

Comment: What you need to know is which statements in *your code* are costing the most time, whether or not the cost is in the form of system calls. That's what [*random pausing*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) does. It won't do any good to have visibility into the kernel, because you can't change anything in there. You need to know about the code *you* can fix.

Comment: Thanks, but , my Kernel has some customized modules, which can be modified by me, so is there any tool I can port on my embedded box which is X86 based to do kernel level profiling.

Comment: OK, in that case I stand corrected. You need samples that reach into the kernel. When I did that, ages ago, I used an in-circuit-emulator. It wasn't easy, but it did find the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). Apparently there is also some effort going on to implement a callgrind [converter](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=136432531919016&w=2).